# How to change the right padding of the MUI Autocomplete Input box?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

By default MUI adds, 65px of right padding to the outlined Autocomplete box. However, I would like to change the right padding to 50px as per my usecases. I am trying to override the right padding but no luck. Here is my sandbox where I tried changing the right padding of the Autocomplete input box - https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-demo-material-ui-forked-95rvqw

Also attaching the screenshots of the Autocomplete box whose padding needs to be changed.

[image: Right padding to be changed]
[image: DOM element whose right padding to be changed]

Can someone please suggest how to override the default right padding of the Autocomplete box ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change your `sx` attribute like this:

```
sx={{
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    paddingRight: "10px!important",
  },
}}
```

**Explanation:**
Your approach is right, but there are some problems that I'll try to correct step by step.

*First of all*, the `&` sign needs to be the first letter of the string followed by a space. For example:

```
"& .MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon"
```

*Second*, You should target the classes one by one, like this:

```
sx={{
  "& .MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon": {
    paddingRight: "50px"
  },
  "& .MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon":{
    paddingRight: "50px"
  },
  "& .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot":{
    paddingRight: "50px"
  },
}}
```

*Third*, You only need to select `.MuiOutlinedInput-root` class for your desired change.

*And lastly*, because (in this case) the classes in the nested component have higher specificity, You need to add `!important` keyword to finish the work.

See the MUI [Documentations on how to customize nested components using the sx prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization)

Comment: Thanks Hamed for sharing this. This works for me. Can you please explain me the need of & operator and what does it signifies ? I am always confused with its usage.

Comment: MUI uses `JSS` for it's styles. In JSS, `&` character means the parent element. So "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root"` will compile to `".MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiOutlinedInput-root"`. In CSS terms it means select elements with `MuiOutlinedInput-root` class that are inside elements with `MuiAutocomplete-root` class. check [JSS example section](https://cssinjs.org/repl/).

Comment: @HamedSiaban do we have any other way without "!important" ?

Comment: @shafavp I don't know if there's any... Please share with us if you could find another way.

Answer (score 1):

This padding (65px) exists for a good reason - in order to not allow input content to overflow the clear button at the end of the input. You can pass `disableClearable` prop to your `Autocomplete` component in order to have padding `6px` from all sides but you will lose the clear button. Otherwise, just overriding the existing padding will lead to collisions between content and the clear button in UI.

```
      <Autocomplete
        disableClearable
        multiple
        ...other props
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MuiAutocomplete: {
  root: {
    "&.MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon.MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon .MuiOutlinedInput- 
     root": {
        paddingRight: 0,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, consider adding some explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged. Especially when answering to old questions with existing upvoted answers: it helps to understand what new idea that was not present in those answers is provided by yours.

Comment: Even if no text is added, this is the answer without using the !important property. Thanks!